# Derived class memory leak

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out the memory leaks that I'm having.

I have these (simplified) classes (can not be changed, I have to work with these):

```
class Base
{
 bool baseBool;
 Base(Base&){};
 virtual ~Base();
}

class Derived1 : public: Base
{
 char* text;
 Derived1(Derived1&);
 ~Derived1();
}

class Derived2 : public: Base
{
 int num;
 Derived2(Derived2&);
 ~Derived()
}
```

Derived1 Copy constructor

```
Derived1::Derived1(Derived1& derived):text("")
{
    text=new char[strlen(text)+1]; //assign enough memory + 1
    strcpy(text,derived.text); //copy existing aText into new objects aText
}
```

Then I have a struct used to manipulate them

```
struct Container
{
 Container& operator=(Container&);
 Base** bases
}
```

In the overloaded operator= for struct Container I'm making a deep copy of the Container objects. Like so:

```
Container& Container::operator=(Container& R)
{
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
        delete bases[i];
    delete[]bases;
    bases=new Base*[MAX];
    for(j=0;j<MAX;j++)
        answers[j]=0;
    for(k=0;k<MAX;k++)
    {
        if(dynamic_cast<Derived1 *>(R.bases[k]))
            bases[k]=new Derived1(*(dynamic_cast<Derived1 *>(R.bases[k])));
        else
            bases[k]=new Derived2(*(dynamic_cast<Derived2 *>(R.bases[k])));
    }
    return *this;
}
```

This part of the code works if I were to assign a newly created Container object using the overloaded = operator

Like so in my main

```
Container containers[2];
bases = new Base*[2];
bases[0] = new Derived1("boooo");
bases[1] = new Derived2(3);
containers[0]=*(new Container(bases)); //uses the overloaded operator= OK
```

But if I were to assign two already made Container objects to each other like so:

```
containers[0]=containers[1];
```

Following debugging it crashes on

```
for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
 delete bases[i];
```

Saying

```
HEAP[ass3.exe]: Heap block at 00729268 modified at 00729295 past requested size of 25
ass3.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
HEAP[ass3.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00720000, 00729270 )
ass3.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

Which is why I think I have memory leaks because Derived1 has a char*.

Glad for any input.

Thanks! I hope I was clear enough...

**Edit**: I do have an empty base copy constructor, and the derived cc does exist as well. Maybe I went to simple for the example.

Comment: Ugh I don't doubt that you have memory leaks. This is why C++ was *invented*. Use `std::vector`

Comment: Did you implement a proper copy constructor also?

Comment: 1) Your base class should have a virtual destructor.  2) You didn't implement the copy constructor.

Comment: `I have these (simplified) classes (can not be changed, I have to work with these):`  Work with classes that don't have the necessary functions for proper memory management?  Your class(es) are missing the copy constructor.

Comment: @R Sahu, by proper, what do I have to look for ? As Derived1 is the only class with pointers I have Edited the post. @everyone the base does have a virtual destructor and all the classes have copy constructors, maybe I went too simple with my example, I edited the post. Thanks for the help, guys.

Comment: Your examples don't even compile. That shows me that _you did not test with those examples_. Try again...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like MAX is a number greater than the size of bases ie. bases may only have 5 entrys while MAX could be 10. In this case, once you get past the end of bases (bases[5] does not exist if the size is only 5 because the numbering starts at 0). I typically use a vector instead of an array and my code for the for loop would look like this:

```
for(i=0;i<bases.size();i++)
 delete bases[i];
```

This ensures that your for loop does not go past the end of bases.

Comment: Thanks for the input but it crashes on the very first iteration. Like I said it works fine if I'm using the operator= on a newly made Container object. Please see my updated OP.

Answer (score 0):

From the example, you've given you need to make sure that the 'bases' member of struct Container itself is actually allocated, and initialized.

From the symptoms you've expressed (crashing on the first iteration), it looks like you're deleting an un-initialized bases pointer (array of pointers), or the actual pointers themselves are not being properly nullptr initialized.

This may be down to your sample code being incomplete however.